# SQL server query to combine multiple rows into single row

Tags: sql-server

[image]

Please help me with the sql query to retrieve a single row for each trip code which will combine all the rows of same trip code into one. For eg: in this example: ASSASSIN - 03 Sep 19 trip code had four columns.

Comment: [Please don't post data and code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Also what have you tried so far, what is the specific part of your solution which does not work properly? Please read [ask] in [help].

Comment: Sample data and expected results as text would help immensely

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` to combine all the rows for the same TripCode, and use aggregate functions to return one of its values for each other column (I've chosen `MAX()` so if one row has the Y value, it will return Y for that trip).

```
Select TripCode, 
       max(VesselName) as VesselName,
       max(Captain) as Captain,
       max([Captain Statement]) as [Captain Statement],
       max([Crew List]) as [Crew List],
       max([Dolphin Safe]) as [Dolphin Safe],
       max(Form 370]) as [Form 370],
       max([Unload Start Date]) as [Unload Start Date],
       max([Unload End Date]) as [Unload End Date]
from MyTable
group by TripCode
```